# Moving the bounds of a Word commentary

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2003

Can I somehow change the bounds of an existing comment in Word (2003)? Rewriting parts of the text that are marked by the comment removes that text from the comment's selection, but that's not what I want.

Comment: Hi, can you please clarify what you mean by commentary?

Comment: @Adam The speech bubbles in the margin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you want to expand the selection of text which marked by a comment without removing and adding that comment again.

I haven't found any way to do this other than deleting the text (which is not a good solution). I see there is another [open question](https://superuser.com/questions/159765/expand-comment-select-in-microsoft-word) about the same thing where someone created a macro for the task which might be of help to you.

Comment: Thanks, that's already better than the expected answer "No, doesn't work." Still not really satifying, that seems like a common enough use case??

Comment: @kutschkem, I agree, but I get the feeling Microsoft didn't want comments edited after being written.